# SWIG Installation Boost Errors

Tags: python, linux, gnu-make, swig

I am installing Swig 3.0.12. This is the first time I have used it. I ran:
**make -k check** after the installation, and it came back with some boost errors. In the case below they are from the Python check, however the errors for boost have appeared in nearly all of the checks. Are these errors that I should look into correcting and if so, any ideas on how I can go about that?

Errors:

```
multiple_inheritance_shared_ptr_wrap.cxx:3131:10: fatal error: 
      'boost/shared_ptr.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [python_cpp] Error 1
make[1]: *** [multiple_inheritance_shared_ptr.cpptest] Error 2
.
. (dots indicate the error below occurred later in the check)
.
make[1]: Target `check' not remade because of errors.
make: *** [check-python-test-suite] Error 1
```

Update: make -k check just completed. The last line of the check returned:
``` make: Target ``check' not remade because of errors. ```

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I had to install home-brew then boost. I did make -k check, again, and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed homebrew then installed boost. Redid make -k check, and everything passed no problem.